# Creating GRAPH, making the link of the elements only if a IF test = TRUE

Tags: python

[image]

Hello, I would like to create a graph in python. I read of an array of a text file, and I have to associate each element of the array with the elements who are on top, under, left, right. As the picture shows, doing tests on the element "0" if the element 1 and element 4 are free. Then generate the graph in the graph model:

```
graph= {0:[1,4], 
        1:[2], ...
    }
```

Found in the documentation that the graph is a dictionary (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) Am I right?

Any tips on how to group the elements in a dictionary linking them with the test is true?

---

My code @TonyBabarino:

In maze.txt:

```
111111111111111111111
121000100000013000001
101011111011111110101
101010000010000000101
101010111110111111101
100010100000100010001
101110001110101010101
100000100010001000101
111111111111111111111
```

Some sections are only for testing.

```
import numpy as np

with open ( 'maze.txt') as buffer:
    M = list(map(int, line.strip()) for line in buffer)

print(np.matrix(M))

def encontra_inicio(matriz): # retorna (x,y) do inicio
    for i in range (len(matriz)):
        for j in range(len(matriz[i])):
            if (matriz[i][j] == 2):
                return [i,j]

def encontra_fim(matriz):
    for i in range (len(matriz)):
        for j in range(len(matriz[i])):
            if (matriz[i][j] == 3):
                return [i,j]

def freePath(M,xy,stack):
    x=xy[0]
    y=xy[1]
    if(xy in stack):
        if( M[x+1][y] == 0 ): #baixo
            jaVisitado([x+1,y],stack)

        if( M[x-1][y] == 0 ): #cima
            jaVisitado([x-1,y],stack)

        if( M[x][y+1] == 0 ): #direita
            jaVisitado([x,y+1],stack)

        if( M[x][y-1] == 0 ): #esquerda
            jaVisitado([x,y-1],stack)
    return

def jaVisitado(xy, stack):
    if( xy not in stack):
        stack.append(xy)
    else:
        return

def posCursor(xy,stack,i):
    aux=i
    x=stack[aux-1][0] #salva a coordenada x da stack na variavel x
    y=stack[aux-1][1] #salva a coordenada y da stack na variavel y
    xy[0]=x
    xy[1]=y
    return xy


i=0
stack=[]
xy=[]
xy=encontra_inicio(M)
stack.append(encontra_inicio(M))

for j in range(20):
    freePath(M,xy,stack)
    posCursor(xy,stack,i)
print i
print
print stack
```

Comment: Do You really have to create a dict graph? Wouldn't that be easier to use a matrix like on Your first image? Also I don't understand what does `IF(M[0][1]==FREE)` mean. What is `FREE`? Give us an example input and expected output for it.

Comment: FREE = 0, BUSY = 1. My matrix is made of 0's and 1's. So I have a maze, where the wall is represented by 1, and free way is represented by 0. I need construct a GRAPH for use in DFS or BFS graph search algorithm.

Comment: Oh ok I understand now. And why don't You want to work on that matrix? You can write a simple function that given a cell in matrix, returns You list of FREE neighbor cells = edges in graph.

Comment: I've done this. But caught in the implementation of BFS and DFS algorithm. Become my problem to generate a graph from the array I already have codes ready on the internet. But the entry must be in the graph format. I've tried to develop my own code from pseudocode and working directly with the matrix, but don't work.

Comment: Post Your code then so we can fix it.

Comment: @TonyBabarino edited. Is incomplete, can not develop based on pseudo wikipedia about bfs and dfs. I know I need do a pop in the list, which is treated as queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, which finds the path in a maze using DFS. It returns some more cells after finishing because there are still some function calls on stack, but I'm sure You will be able to tune it, so it fits better with Your problem.

```
import numpy as np
from sets import Set

with open('maze.txt') as buffer:
    M = np.matrix(list(map(int, line.strip()) for line in buffer))

print M

def encontra_inicio(matriz):  # retorna (x,y) do inicio
    foo = np.where(M == 2)
    return foo[0][0], foo[1][0]

def freePath(M, xy, visited):
    print str(xy) + '->',
    x = xy[0]
    y = xy[1]
    if M[x+1, y] == 3 or M[x-1, y] == 3 or M[x, y+1] == 3 or M[x, y-1] == 3:
        print 'FINISHED!'
        return
    if M[x+1, y] == 0 and not (x+1, y) in visited:
        visited.add((x+1, y))
        freePath(M, (x+1, y), visited)
    if M[x-1, y] == 0 and not (x-1, y) in visited:
        visited.add((x-1, y))
        freePath(M, (x-1, y), visited)
    if M[x, y+1] == 0 and not (x, y+1) in visited:
        visited.add((x, y+1))
        freePath(M, (x, y+1), visited)
    if M[x, y-1] == 0 and not (x, y-1) in visited:
        visited.add((x, y-1))
        freePath(M, (x, y-1), visited)
    return

visited = Set([])
xy = encontra_inicio(M)
freePath(M, xy, visited)
```

returns:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 2 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
(1, 1)-> (2, 1)-> (3, 1)-> (4, 1)-> (5, 1)-> (6, 1)-> (7, 1)-> (7, 2)-> (7, 3)-> (7, 4)-> (7, 5)-> (6, 5)-> (5, 5)-> (4, 5)-> (3, 5)-> (3, 6)-> (3, 7)-> (3, 8)-> (3, 9)-> (2, 9)-> (1, 9)-> (1, 10)-> (1, 11)-> (1, 12)-> (1, 8)-> (1, 7)-> (6, 6)-> (6, 7)-> (7, 7)-> (7, 8)-> (7, 9)-> (5, 7)-> (5, 8)-> (5, 9)-> (5, 10)-> (5, 11)-> (6, 11)-> (7, 11)-> (7, 12)-> (7, 13)-> (6, 13)-> (5, 13)-> (5, 14)-> (5, 15)-> (6, 15)-> (7, 15)-> (7, 16)-> (7, 17)-> (6, 17)-> (5, 17)-> (5, 18)-> (5, 19)-> (6, 19)-> (7, 19)-> (4, 19)-> (3, 19)-> (2, 19)-> (1, 19)-> (1, 18)-> (1, 17)-> (2, 17)-> (3, 17)-> (3, 16)-> (3, 15)-> (3, 14)-> (3, 13)-> (3, 12)-> (3, 11)-> (4, 11)-> (1, 16)-> (1, 15)-> FINISHED!
(5, 2)-> (5, 3)-> (4, 3)-> (3, 3)-> (2, 3)-> (1, 3)-> (1, 4)-> (1, 5)->
```